# What batteries allow very fast charging times?

Tags: battery-chemistry

I have read that some batteries are able to be charged in 5 minutes.

What battery chemistries allows this rate of charging?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have no idea what this is about, but there's certainly no way in which it could be on topic for this site. Is this about some kind of chemical modelling/simulation system? Try the chemistry SE.

Comment: The tag "battery-chemistry" suggests "loading" is referring to the charging process of batteries.

Comment: It’s for batteries, store-dot.com claim they can charge in 5 minutes

Comment: @IssaYazigi your question still makes no resemblance of sense. You charge a battery. You can't charge molecules (in the battery sense). Are you sure you understand what a molecule is and how a battery works?

Comment: This is most likely a question better suited for the StackExchange Chemistry forum at:      https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree that unless this question is more about building a battery charger than it is about the actual battery charging process it belongs in a chemistry forum.  _Wherever_ it belongs, however, it needs more detail -- you should say what battery chemistry you're talking about (or be specific that you mean many chemistries), what process (charge or discharge) you're talking about, and it's usually a good idea to say _why_ you're asking (idle curiosity, you're building a battery charger, choosing battery chemistries, choosing a particular battery within a chemistry, etc.).

Comment: People are unable to understand what you are asking. Molecules are not batteries. If there is a link please provide it. ||Lithium Titanate batteries can be charged in about 5 minutes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-titanate_battery

Comment: **DOWNVOTERS** Please read the edited question. The original suffered from "lost in translation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lithium Titanate batteries can be charged in about 5 minutes.

Details can be found on Wikipedia here

Good summary byEVLitghium [here](https://www.evlithium.com/lithium-titanate-battery-lto/)

Many links [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=lithium+titanate++battery+LTO&sca_esv=572078159&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AM9HkKmPpoc6-gLl8zuVjIHlYNIO4-8Q2A:1696929406147&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB_tjTkuuBAxVDsFYBHWH7CLMQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1920&bih=948&dpr=2) - each image links to a related web page.